# Dockers: external drive as shared volume in OSX, Permissions

Tags: macos, docker, permissions

First let me describe the system that I'm working on.

### Intro

- I've got a Mac with a small SSD drive. The system contains different
  tools for data analysis that run as separated dockers.
- Docker for OSX does not run directly on the system and it requires a
  linux-based Virtual Machine which runs the dockers internally.
- Some of these tools store huge amounts of data (several TB), which means that the internal HDD would not be enough so we need to store the data in an external media.

Therefore, for each docker it would be interesting to **separate the data storage (databases) and the system files** (OS + tool sources). Databases must be stored at the external HDD.

What I've done is:

1. Create a **shared directory** at the external HDD between OSX and the Linux-based VM (host for the dockers). Let's say that this directory is mounted at **"/data"** within the Linux VM.
2. Then, when creating a docker, use the "/data" directory from host as a volume mounted at the "/data" directory of the docker. If I *ssh* to one of the created dockers and list the content of the "/data" dir, I can see the content of the external HDD. So that works.

Here is when the problem appears, and it is related with **PERMISSIONS**.

### PROBLEM

Considering that:

- At the OSX our user is *peterfoo*
- At the dockers the main user is also *peterfoo*, but we may have secondary users for the different system services. For example, if we install MYSQL, the MySQL service will be executed by default by the user *mysql* and all the files will belong to this user.
- I want to change the MySQL data directory to enforce that all the data is stored at the "/data" directory (i.e. at the external HDD)

If I user the user *peterfoo* there is not problem: I can write files, read files, remove and create directories, etc. at the "/data" directory (external HDD) from the docker. However, using a different user the system does not allow writting, which means that when the *mysql* user tries to write/read data from the new location it fails and MySQL stops working.

### SOLUTIONS?

I couldn't find a solution at this forum and I've being trying to fix this issue from yesterday.

The only solution that I found for the moment is a really naive one: run the MySQL (and other services) as the *peterfoo* user, instead of the correspoding one (*mysql*). This is not a critical issue but introduces a security problem: it is always recomendable to use specific users for the system services to keep control of the access to data.

Any idea?

Thanks!!

### More info

If I run `ls -l` to /data directory, I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x    8 peterfoo  staff   272B 17 may 09:48 app1-data/
drwxr-xr-x    3 peterfoo  staff   102B 25 may 12:38 app2-data/
drwxr-xr-x    7 peterfoo  staff   238B 25 abr 10:35 app3-data/
```

If I try to change the ownership of the directory to *mysql*, it doesn't work and keeps *peterfoo*.

```
$ sudo chown mysql:mysql /data/app1-data
$ ls -l /data | grep app1
drwxr-xr-x    8 peterfoo  staff   272B 17 may 09:48 app1-data/
```

If also tries changing the rwx permissions to 777 and then using a secondary user (let's say user2) can create dirs and files but once created, the ownership changes automatically to peterfoo, and the created subdirectories become unwritable to user2.

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /data/app1-data
$ ls -l /data | grep app1
drwxrwxrwx    8 peterfoo  staff   272B 17 may 09:48 app1-data/
$ su user2
$ touch test.txt
$ mkdir /data/app1-data/test
$ ls -l /data/app1-data/
drwxrwxrwx 1 peterfoo staff 204 May 25 12:38 ./
drwxrwxr-x 1 peterfoo staff 510 May 24 14:29 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 peterfoo staff   0 May 25 08:07 test.txt
drwxr-xr-x 1 peterfoo staff  68 May 25 12:38 test/
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm let me get this straight:
you got a virtual machine for linux to wich you attached part of the external storage; you then mounted that storage at /data in linux system.

created a docker container with a volume at /data inside the container mounted at /data inside the linux vm.

if i got that right the docker should automatically have permission to write in /data at linux vm and the only problems i can think of are the permission that are set inside the docker at the /data directory.

if my hunch is right when you ssh inside the docker and ls -l at / you will find owner is peterfoo and lacking permission for other users

Comment: Yes, but if I run the MySQL service using the default _mysql_ user then when the service tries to write at the /data directory, it fails because the /data directory only allows writing to peterfoo. 
Please take a look to the **more info** section that I added above.

Comment: Check the partition type df -T  if its NTFS or FAT they do not support permission. 

check this answer for details and mounting option http://superuser.com/questions/57092/cant-change-permission-ownership-group-of-external-hard-drive-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks! It was related with the partition type. The HDD was in HFS+ format (OSX) but when I mounted it at the VM, I used the vboxsf format (virtual box file sharing format). Using this format I was not able to change the R/W permissions. Now I'm using NFS to mount the shared folder between OSX and the VM and I pass over the problem. References: http://yas.ch/blog/2015/04/10/file-sharing-in-docker/ and https://gist.github.com/pointcom/b72ecd2709aba789e881